# C++ If, else if not reading else if. OR Find function incorrect?

Tags: c++, if-statement, find

I can't quite figure this out. The program builds no problem. The issue is that no matter what the user input is, the if statement goes ahead and the program does not check the else if statement. I assume there's a larger structural problem in my script, but I'm not sure what it is.

It could be a problem with the find function. I'm still new to this function.

It could also be to do with how I'm nesting this new if-else-if statement within another if statement.

The problem comes towards the end of the code, in the final if-else-if. I'm pasting the whole thing in case it's a deeper issue elsewhere in the code. The previous if statement works fine. Here's the specific piece of code with the problem:

```
if (song.find(str2)){
        cout << "Thank you! I, personally, love this song.\n";
        cout << "I probably wouldn't listen to you if you asked me to turn it off.\n";
        Sleep(20000);
    }
    else if (song.find(str3)){
        cout << "It's not coming off, " << name <<"." << endl;
    }
```

Thanks for any help. Much appreciated :)

Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int emotion;


void Sleep()
{
    Sleep();
}

void loneliness()
{
    cout << "Lonely. You must be strong, and loved, if you choose this feeling to explore.";
}

void inlove()
{
    cout << "In love. You've been watching telenovelas again.";
}

void ambitious()
{
    cout << "Ambitious. Steve Jobs Steve Jobs.";
}

void happy()
{
    cout << "Happy. Is this a thing you can just feel?";
}

int main() {

    string input;
    string input2;
    string name;

cout << "I'm bad." << endl;
cout << "My name's Raab." << endl;
cout << "Your name?" << endl;
getline(cin, name);
cout << "Tell me in one word what emotion you're feeling right now." << endl;
getline(cin, input);
cout << "Haha. " << input << "?" << " " << "Alright. I can work with that." << endl;

cout << "..." << endl;
cout << "Okay, I'm going to give you a choice." << endl;
cout << "You can trade that emotion for one other, if you'd like." << endl;
cout << "Would you like to do that?" << endl;
getline(cin, input2);

if (input2 == "Yes" && "yes") {

    int emotion;

    cout << "Nice one, bro.\n";
    Sleep(350);
    cout << "Here are your options!\n";
    Sleep(300);
    cout << "1. Lonely\n";
    cout << "2. In love.\n";
    cout << "3. Ambitious.\n";
    cout << "4. Happy.\n";
    cin >> emotion;

switch (emotion) {
case 1:
    loneliness();
    break;
case 2:
    inlove();
    break;
case 3:
    ambitious();
    break;
case 4:
    happy();
    break;
}
cin.get();


}

else if (input2 == "No" && "no")
{

    std::string song;
    std::string str2 ("like");
    std::string str3 ("off");

    cout << "Well" << endl;
    Sleep(250);
    PlaySound(TEXT("whip"), NULL, SND_ASYNC|SND_FILENAME);
    cout << "." << endl;
    Sleep(300);
    PlaySound(TEXT("whip"), NULL, SND_ASYNC|SND_FILENAME);
    cout << "." << endl;
    Sleep(300);
    PlaySound(TEXT("whip"), NULL, SND_ASYNC|SND_FILENAME);
    cout << "." << endl;
    Sleep(300);
    PlaySound(TEXT("gravity"), NULL, SND_ASYNC|SND_FILENAME);
    Sleep(2500);
    cout << "Here we go. You like this song? Or do you want me to turn it off?\n";
    Sleep(2000);
    cout <<"Wait.\n";
    Sleep(2000);
    cout << "Don't tell me yet. I'm grooving.\n";
    Sleep(7000);
    cout << "Okay, tell me what to do, " << name << "." << endl;
    getline(cin, song);

    if (song.find(str2)){
        cout << "Thank you! I, personally, love this song.\n";
        cout << "I probably wouldn't listen to you if you asked me to turn it off.\n";
        Sleep(20000);
    }
    else if (song.find(str3)){
        cout << "It's not coming off, " << name <<"." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    }

return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:

I sort of fixed the issue.

I changed the above extract of code to this:

```
if (~song.find(str2))
    {
        cout << "Thank you! I, personally, love this song.\n";
        cout << "I probably wouldn't listen to you if you asked me to turn it off.\n";
        Sleep(20000);
    }
    else if (!~song.find(str2))
    {
        cout << "It's not coming off, " << name <<"." << endl;
        Sleep(20000);
    }
```

So it doesn't check for str3 anymore, but it does check if str2 is absent. This is progress, and fudges a solution, but it doesn't really give me a deeper understanding that I can bring forward with me so I would still appreciate answers :)
**

Comment: `input2 == "Yes" && "yes"` is equivalent to `input2 == "Yes"` because `"yes"` will be always true in typical environments. `input2 == "No" && "no"` is also equivalent to `input2 == "No"`

Comment: @MikeCAT in typical environment? Do you mean there is an environment where string literal will be equal to `nullptr`?

Comment: "The issue is that no matter what the user input is, the if statement goes ahead and the program does not check the else if statement." Are you sure? I typed `like` and the program correctly printed The "It's not coming off, " part. My environment is GCC 4.8.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: That's interesting. Though in my mind "like" should offer the other "Thank you" response and it is "off" that should offer "It's not coming off." However, it still only offers me the "Thank you" response no matter what I type.

Answer (score 4):

The line is incorrect :

```
if (input2 == "Yes" && "yes")
```

The `&&` doesn't work that way. You have to perform the comparison with each value in the if statement. It should be:

```
if(input2 == "Yes" || input2 =="yes")
```

Likewise, the line

```
else if (input2 == "No" && "no")
```

should be:

```
if(input2 == "No" || input2 =="no")
```

Comment: Thank you, I should have specified that it is the if-else-if statement after this that has the problem. I originally used the OR boolean for this statement, but it gave me problems. I will fix this now, though.

Comment: No problem. Keep up with the good work, and let us know if you have further questions.

Comment: @AmandaC.Cavallaro: Please don't encourage people to "let us know"... the workload on StackOverflow is horrible as is :-)  anyway, +1

Comment: @einpoklum Thank you! 